# Analytic family of functions and Lipschitz continuity

Tags: analysis, lipschitz-functions, analytic-functions

Let $f_t:U_t\rightarrow V_t$ be an analytic family of homeomorphisms, where $0\leq t\leq 1$, and $U_t, V_t\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded domains. Moreover, there exist $c,C>0$ such that for all x,y,t:

$$c\cdot \vert x-y \vert\leq \vert f_t(x)-f_t(y) \vert\leq C\cdot \vert x-y \vert.$$

I want to show that all derivatives $\frac{d^n}{dt^n} f _{\vert t=t_0}:U_{t_0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ are Lipschitz continuous for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to prove this claim. Since $f$ is analytic, there is an interval $I_{\epsilon}:=(t_0-\epsilon, t_0+\epsilon)$ such that for all $t\in I_{\epsilon}$:

$$f_t(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d^n}{dt^n} f _{\vert t=t_0}(x)\cdot (t-t_0)^n.$$

I think this might help.But I do not know exactly what to do next. If you know how to prove the result, please help me.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false in general. Let $U_t=V_t=\mathbb{R}^2$ for all $t$.  For $0\le t\le 1$  define $f_t$ by 
$$
f_t(x_1, x_2) = (x_1, x_2 + \sin (tx_1))
$$
This is an analytic function of $x_1, x_2, t$. It is Lipschitz continuous with respect to $(x_1, x_2)$ with Lipschitz constant at most $3$. The same holds for its inverse, which is 
$$
f_t^{-1}(x_1, x_2) = (x_1, x_2 - \sin (tx_1))
$$
However, 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}f_t(x_1, x_2) = (x_1, x_2 + x_1\cos (tx_1))
$$
is not Lipschitz continuous, as its derivative with respect to $x_1$ is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I need some time to think about your nice example. So if we assume $U_t, V_t$ to be compact, then the statement is correct?!

Comment: I have one more question: How do you know that $f_t$ and $df_t/dt$ are smooth in x (in the general setting)? By assumption the functions $f_t$ are only Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: My remark at the end was based on a misreading of the question; I deleted it.